# "Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate" - how can I make a Storyboard happy with iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: ios7, storyboard, segue, ios8, xcode6

I created a project in Xcode6, beta 6 or so (upgraded to b7 today). Using Swift, been developing for the iOS 8 SDK, etc.

The Storyboard, so far, has two View Controllers, and a segue between the two set up as "Show" (it's not triggered by a button directly, it's handled by a successful login)

[image]

Everything is groovy. And then I tried running the app on the iOS 7.1 simulator. It dies on the first screen with this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: 'Could not instantiate class named 
UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate'
```

Well, seeing as how "Show" is listed as an "Adaptive Segue", and Adaptive UI is pretty much an iOS 8 concept, it makes sense that iOS 7 would have an issue with it.

Since they've gone so far as to basically say "look, this is what we used to call Push", I figure I'll change the Segue to "Push". Sure, it's deprecated, but I'll just ditch it when iOS 8 takes over.

Except that if I use it I get a warning

[image]

Well crap, I don't want to see some annoying warning, but I'm not sure I want to give up iOS 7 compatibility yet (though it's not out of the question). And this isn't in code so I can't suppress the warning (or I don't know how).

How can I make a Storyboard Segue that's happy in both iOS 7 and 8 in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can still use the new Segue type (such as Show) for iOS 7. Make sure in your Storyboard interface builder document, set the "Builds for" to iOS 7 rather than iOS8. (Sorry the screenshot is prepared but I have no enough reputation to post it)

Inside the `File Inspector` select the lowest:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This just solved my problem. I added, the missing screenshot ;)

Answer (score 1):

As i am also getting the same issue with my project. I get this resolved by rechecking all segues i defined in the app. Make sure all segues will have some action like push/pop/modal.

If not then on that controller app will crash. Please check below snapshot which you will find in your storyboard.

your storyboard image will look like first image.

[image]

Make cure segue is selected.

[image]