# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException, UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboard in which there is UINavigationController. View controllers are popped and pushed.

The issue is , when i push a UIViewController i take the exception on iOS 7, it works fine on iOS 8.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate'
```

What can be the problem?

Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

As i am also getting the same issue with my project. I get this resolved by rechecking all segues i defined in the app. Make sure all segues will have some action like push/pop/modal.

If not then on that controller app will crash. Please check below snapshot which you will find in your storyboard.

Refer a solution on below link.

["Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate" - how can I make a Storyboard happy with iOS 7 and iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633739/could-not-instantiate-class-named-uistoryboardshowseguetemplate-how-can-i-ma/28559742#28559742)