# App work on iOS 8 but don't work on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Please help me, app work on iOS 8 but when I launch in iOS 7.1 Simulator it stopped working.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate'

*** First throw call stack:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x014a61e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c8c8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   CoreFoundation                      0x014a5fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139

3   UIKit                               0x008eabd9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 300

4   UIKit                               0x008eaf6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217

5   UIKit                               0x008eaaa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114

6   UIKit                               0x005eb5f9 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 758

7   UIKit                               0x007a2aa4 -[UITableViewController initWithCoder:] + 58

8   fmeiapp                             0x0007bc78 _TFC7fmeiapp23FeedTableViewControllercfMS0_FT5coderCSo7NSCoder_S0_ + 328

9   fmeiapp                             0x0007bdbf _TToFC7fmeiapp23FeedTableViewControllercfMS0_FT5coderCSo7NSCoder_S0_ + 47

10  UIKit                               0x00785c11 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 240

11  UIKit                               0x008ead6d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704

12  UIKit                               0x008eaaa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114

13  UIKit                               0x007857a7 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 191

14  UIKit                               0x00785f07 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 58

15  UIKit                               0x008ead6d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704

16  UIKit                               0x008eaf6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217

17  UIKit                               0x008eaaa1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114

18  UIKit                               0x00784c21 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1117

19  UIKit                               0x00a338bd -[UIStoryboard
```

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 220

```
20  UIKit                               0x00a33a36 -[UIStoryboard
```

instantiateInitialViewController] + 74

```
21  UIKit                               0x004cf6ac -[UIApplication
```

_loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 79

```
22  UIKit                               0x004cf949 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245

23  UIKit                               0x004ce54e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543

24  UIKit                               0x004e2f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] +
```

3517

```
25  UIKit                               0x004e3555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85

26  UIKit                               0x004d0250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683

27  GraphicsServices                    0x03532f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776

28  GraphicsServices                    0x03532a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46

29  CoreFoundation                      0x01421ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53

30  CoreFoundation                      0x014219db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523

31  CoreFoundation                      0x0144c68c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156

32  CoreFoundation                      0x0144b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467

33  CoreFoundation                      0x0144b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

34  UIKit                               0x004cdd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840

35  UIKit                               0x004cff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225

36  fmeiapp                             0x000b8a4e top_level_code + 78

37  fmeiapp                             0x000b8a8b main + 43

38  libdyld.dylib                       0x031206d9 start + 1

39  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator ?

Comment: Yes, I resetting simulator but this don't help me

Comment: I think this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633739/could-not-instantiate-class-named-uistoryboardshowseguetemplate-how-can-i-ma